# Car counter arduino program, how to stop counting when car is stopped on sensor.

Tags: arduino, embedded

I'm using a pressure sensor (mpx5010gp) and a plastic pipe connected to an arduino board to count the number of cars passing over it. Whenever the sensor value goes above a threshold *or an average*, that is calculated dynamically, as a car passes over the pipe, the counter goes up by one. The problem I am facing is the counter continuing to increase if a certain car stops on the pipe.

This is how the calculations are done:

```
  void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);

  if(millis()<2000)
  {
      averageValue +=((float)sensorValue-averageValue)/10.f;  
  }else 
  {
    if(sensorValue>averageValue +4){
      count++;
      Serial.println(count);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print(count);
      averageValue =sensorValue+10;
      delay(2000);
    }
    else 
    {
        averageValue +=((float)sensorValue-averageValue)/100.f; 
    }     
  }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the obvious: implement a hysteresis, you also most likely need to add some manner of simple digital filter, such as a median 3 filter. And why are you using floating point? It will kill everything that is performance and memory inside your poor little 8-bitter. Arduino is not a PC.

Answer (score 3):

Have two thresholds with hysteresis, so that you increment the count when the high threshold is exceeded and do not increment the count further until the level falls below the lower threshold.

```
void setup()
{
    active = false ;
}

void loop()
{
    sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
    if( sensorValue > high_threshold && !active )
    {
        count++ ;
        active = true ;
    }

    if( sensorValue < low_threshold )
    {
        active = false ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only count rising edges (i.e. the transition from low to high)

By the way, your handling of values is near incomprehensible.  Divide by 10.0 sometimes.  100 other times.   Wait for 2s, add 4 here, 10 there.

If I were grading your code, I'd give it at best a barely passing grade.

Comment: These values were added after many trials and errors, trying to increasing the accuracy of the count. How would you implement that (counting the rising edges)

Comment: By remembering the previous state. If the pipe is pressed, you count 1 axle and wait until it is not pressed - similar to polling a keyboard. So `loop` could contain two loops: first loop waits until the pipe is pressed, second loop waits until pipe is not pressed.

Comment: @m0hhh separate the logic.   Move all of the sampling and averaging stuff into a function `bool is_plate_pressed()`.   Then have your main loop look at the value of that function and count how many times it goes from `false` to `true`.  Now your counting logic is separated from  your measuring logic.

Comment: Is it like a bounce logic here no? Also, do you consider the car passing over the pressure sensor with the front wheels and rear wheels? Because otherwise if you do not consider, it would count as 2 cars I guess.

Comment: @phyloflash I am sure OP knows most vehicles have 2 axles. Commercial sensors typically have **two** parallel sensors which give the vehicle speed, and direction of travel - unless confused by opposite traffic, so the algorithm would weed out absurd data, and compile statistics.

Comment: @phyloflash Yes cars passing with both axles is taken into consideration.

Comment: @RussSchultz Will try having a bool "active" that will equal true whenever the sensor value is greater than the threshold, and false when it is less than. Only counting when the active == true as another user suggested. What do you think?